# 1407. Top Travellers ending in runtime error

Tags: sql, oracle

I attempted the 1407. [Top Travellers](https://leetcode.com/problems/top-travellers/). But am struggling with my Oracle query below, `'Runtime error'`. A little too tired to understand why. Any idea where I am going wrong? Have been rusty with SQL of late. :(

```
select name as name, 
case when rides.distance is null then 0 else sum(rides.distance) end as travelled_distance
from users
left join rides
on users.id = rides.user_id
group by rides.users_id
order by travelled_distance desc, name;
```

Comment: You probably need the SUM round the CASE rather than CASE round the SUM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below solution works. Thanks to one of the Discussion posts at leetcode I could figure out the issue:

```
select r.name, 
case when x.td is null
then 0
else x.td
end travelled_distance
from Users r
left join
(
    select user_id, sum(distance) td
    from Rides 
    group by user_id
) x
on r.id = x.user_id
order by travelled_distance desc,  r.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

As commented, is another way round:

```
select 
  name,
  sum(case when rides.distance is null then 0 else rides.distance end) as travelled_distance
from users left join rides on users.id = rides.user_id
group by name
order by travelled_distance desc, name;
```

Or, simpler, use the `nvl` function:

```
select 
  name,
  sum(nvl(rides.distance, 0)) as travelled_distance
from ...
```

Though, a few more objections:

- you should use table aliases (as they simplify query and improve readability)

  - moreover, you should precede **all** column names with table aliases; in your case, you failed to do so for the `name` column. It *probably* belongs to the `users` table, but we can't tell for sure as we don't have your data model nor access to your database
- `group by` clause should contain column(s) that aren't aggregated. In your query, that's the `name` column. You *can* put `rides.users_id` into that clause, but you **must** put `name` in there

Comment: hi @Littlefoot,  i have given the link to the actual problem in my description. the solution you answered though fails in leetcode :(

Comment: In the above solution, 'group by name' defeats the answer as two ids can have the same name